# Desktop Bridge App Permission "This app can Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry"

Tags: uwp, windows-store, desktop-bridge

I have converted the Desktop app to the UWP app. Since the desktop app is converted to the UWP app "**runFullTrust**" capability will get added automatically to the package manifest file.

After the app is submitted I can see in the app store that the permission for my app says "**This app can Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry**".

Is this normal for the desktop apps converted this way. Or if there is some way to remove this line. **"This app can Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry"**."

Comment: It's normal as runFullTrust permission translates to the text you see on the Store.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz If there is a way to remove runFullTrust capability as I do not want these unnecessary permissions. ?

Comment: Then you need to make a UWP app not a converted (Desktop Bridge) app.

Answer (score 3):

> This app can Access all your files, peripheral devices, apps, programs, and registry

This description is the default description displayed after adding `runFullTrust` capability.

As a converted desktop bridge application, `runFullTrust` is a must-have capability, which allows them to access to all the available Windows resources so that most of the Win32 code will just work as it is.

You can find the related description in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/archive/blogs/appconsult/a-simpler-and-faster-way-to-publish-your-desktop-bridge-applications-on-the-microsoft-store).